# How to replace google search when long-press home button

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Sorry I'm just a newbie, I want to write an application myself. My idea is when I long press the home button. Instead of google search or google now called, my application will be called. With a newbie, I really need to be instructed on which keyword to use to accomplish this task. Sorry if my question wastes your time

Comment: Do not hesitate to ask questions but first you have to make a deep google search before asking. Normally that action is handled by android core and I am not so sure that there is a method that overrides it.

Comment: you can do nothing from your side to implement it. Some devices have settings section which enables them to set custom action on the home long click.